# Constitutional isomers for four carbon thioesters

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

**Question:**

> How many isomers are there for thioesters with the formula $\ce{C4H8OS}$?

Answer given is four.

I can see that the following two are possible constitutional isomers:

[image: two attempts by OP on thioester]

But what are the other two?

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex="" ‎at="" ‎chemistry.se""="), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-‎we-correct-math-formatting) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-‎stuff-here) on how to make your future posts better.‎

Comment: When I tell you, that dithioesters exist ... will this be a hint?

Comment: Here's my hint: Formic acid exists.

Comment: @jerepierre Didn't thought of that. But then there are more possibilities than 4.

Comment: @PH13 How you can have a dithioester with only one sulfur?

Comment: I never said that the dithioester would be the answer.

Comment: @PH13 I read you now. I didn't realize those isomeric possibilities were still called thioesters. Should be 8 possibilities then, yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26218/discussion-between-ph13-and-jerepierre).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to break things down in by the number of carbon atoms on either "side" of the thioester.

There are 4 carbon atoms to work with, of which one will be taken up by the thioester moiety.  Thus there are three left to work with.

On the carbonyl "side" of the thioester, between zero and three carbons are possible.  However, on the sulfur "side" of the thioester, at least one carbon atom is required; otherwise the compound is not a thioester but a thioacid.  Thus the possibilities for carbon atom distribution are:

- one carbon on S side, two on CO side.
- two carbons on S side, one on CO side.
- three carbons on S side, zero on CO side.

You have drawn the only structures for the first two possibilities.

For the last possibility, there are *two* possible ways to attach a three-carbon alkyl chain to the thioester sulfur:

- as a $n$-propyl group
- as an isopropyl group

Thus, the four possible thioesters are:

1. methyl thiopropanoate
2. ethyl thioacetate
3. n-propyl thioformate
4. isopropyl thioformate

Comment: Actually, it looks like due to haphazard naming of thionoesters (where the O and S atoms of the thioester moiety are reversed), it is less ambiguous to say S-propyl thioformate and S-isopropyl thioformate, etc., at least for formates.  People apparently use the name O-propyl thioformate for the thionoester, confusingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Curt F. I already did consider the two additions you made to my answer but here is the thing: I googled the general formula for thioester and the following image showed up:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Thioester-2D-A.svg/150px-Thioester-2D-A.svg.png

So the two additions (formates) you made to my answer can only be achieved by replacing R(in the image) with H. Is that allowed?

Comment: What people mean by `R` varies by context.  In this case, according my understanding of your question and my understanding of the definition of `thioester`, the `R` bonded to the carbonyl carbon _could_ be H, but the `R'` bonded to the sulfur could not.  Unfortunately there isn't a general answer for what folks mean by `R` in organic chemistry.

Comment: Thanks for you input. Just to make sure, is there some link you can share where I could verify what you said and read more about `thioesters`? I haven't been able to find one by myself.

Answer (score -3):

[image]

if you get stuck drawing more than 2 isomers what i do is take a carbon out and put it somewhere else if you need any more help lmk and on 3 i messed up on the chemical equation but the structure is correct